# Need sample code on bulk api, for beginners

Tags: bulk-api, java

Can any one plz help me in understanding and implementing Bulk API.

Can i get a **small sample code** which clearly demonstrates how bulk API works.

I am totally new to this.

(I have initially worked with SOAP api only)

Please help.

Comment: There is some pretty good documentation and sample code. Have you successfully implemented that example code? If not, what problems did you have?

Comment: @Peace: please check out the documentation and try to make your question more specific. As it is, it is very broad and likely to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code, you can find more information here http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/Content/asynch_api_code_walkthrough.htm

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import com.sforce.async.*;
import com.sforce.soap.partner.PartnerConnection;
import com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException;
import com.sforce.ws.ConnectorConfig;



public class BulkExample {


    public static void main(String[] args)
      throws AsyncApiException, ConnectionException, IOException {
        BulkExample example = new BulkExample();
        // Replace arguments below with your credentials and test file name
        // The first parameter indicates that we are loading Account records
        example.runSample("Account", "myUser@myOrg.com", "myPassword", "mySampleData.csv");
    }

    /**
     * Creates a Bulk API job and uploads batches for a CSV file.
     */
    public void runSample(String sobjectType, String userName,
              String password, String sampleFileName)
            throws AsyncApiException, ConnectionException, IOException {
        BulkConnection connection = getBulkConnection(userName, password);
        JobInfo job = createJob(sobjectType, connection);
        List<BatchInfo> batchInfoList = createBatchesFromCSVFile(connection, job,
            sampleFileName);
        closeJob(connection, job.getId());
        awaitCompletion(connection, job, batchInfoList);
        checkResults(connection, job, batchInfoList);
    }



    /**
     * Gets the results of the operation and checks for errors.
     */
    private void checkResults(BulkConnection connection, JobInfo job,
              List<BatchInfo> batchInfoList)
            throws AsyncApiException, IOException {
        // batchInfoList was populated when batches were created and submitted
        for (BatchInfo b : batchInfoList) {
            CSVReader rdr =
              new CSVReader(connection.getBatchResultStream(job.getId(), b.getId()));
            List<String> resultHeader = rdr.nextRecord();
            int resultCols = resultHeader.size();

            List<String> row;
            while ((row = rdr.nextRecord()) != null) {
                Map<String, String> resultInfo = new HashMap<String, String>();
                for (int i = 0; i < resultCols; i++) {
                    resultInfo.put(resultHeader.get(i), row.get(i));
                }
                boolean success = Boolean.valueOf(resultInfo.get("Success"));
                boolean created = Boolean.valueOf(resultInfo.get("Created"));
                String id = resultInfo.get("Id");
                String error = resultInfo.get("Error");
                if (success && created) {
                    System.out.println("Created row with id " + id);
                } else if (!success) {
                    System.out.println("Failed with error: " + error);
                }
            }
        }
    }



    private void closeJob(BulkConnection connection, String jobId)
          throws AsyncApiException {
        JobInfo job = new JobInfo();
        job.setId(jobId);
        job.setState(JobStateEnum.Closed);
        connection.updateJob(job);
    }



    /**
     * Wait for a job to complete by polling the Bulk API.
     * 
     * @param connection
     *            BulkConnection used to check results.
     * @param job
     *            The job awaiting completion.
     * @param batchInfoList
     *            List of batches for this job.
     * @throws AsyncApiException
     */
    private void awaitCompletion(BulkConnection connection, JobInfo job,
          List<BatchInfo> batchInfoList)
            throws AsyncApiException {
        long sleepTime = 0L;
        Set<String> incomplete = new HashSet<String>();
        for (BatchInfo bi : batchInfoList) {
            incomplete.add(bi.getId());
        }
        while (!incomplete.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            System.out.println("Awaiting results..." + incomplete.size());
            sleepTime = 10000L;
            BatchInfo[] statusList =
              connection.getBatchInfoList(job.getId()).getBatchInfo();
            for (BatchInfo b : statusList) {
                if (b.getState() == BatchStateEnum.Completed
                  || b.getState() == BatchStateEnum.Failed) {
                    if (incomplete.remove(b.getId())) {
                        System.out.println("BATCH STATUS:\n" + b);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }



    /**
     * Create a new job using the Bulk API.
     * 
     * @param sobjectType
     *            The object type being loaded, such as "Account"
     * @param connection
     *            BulkConnection used to create the new job.
     * @return The JobInfo for the new job.
     * @throws AsyncApiException
     */
    private JobInfo createJob(String sobjectType, BulkConnection connection)
          throws AsyncApiException {
        JobInfo job = new JobInfo();
        job.setObject(sobjectType);
        job.setOperation(OperationEnum.insert);
        job.setContentType(ContentType.CSV);
        job = connection.createJob(job);
        System.out.println(job);
        return job;
    }



    /**
     * Create the BulkConnection used to call Bulk API operations.
     */
    private BulkConnection getBulkConnection(String userName, String password)
          throws ConnectionException, AsyncApiException {
        ConnectorConfig partnerConfig = new ConnectorConfig();
        partnerConfig.setUsername(userName);
        partnerConfig.setPassword(password);
        partnerConfig.setAuthEndpoint("https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/29.0");
        // Creating the connection automatically handles login and stores
        // the session in partnerConfig
        new PartnerConnection(partnerConfig);
        // When PartnerConnection is instantiated, a login is implicitly
        // executed and, if successful,
        // a valid session is stored in the ConnectorConfig instance.
        // Use this key to initialize a BulkConnection:
        ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();
        config.setSessionId(partnerConfig.getSessionId());
        // The endpoint for the Bulk API service is the same as for the normal
        // SOAP uri until the /Soap/ part. From here it's '/async/versionNumber'
        String soapEndpoint = partnerConfig.getServiceEndpoint();
        String apiVersion = "29.0";
        String restEndpoint = soapEndpoint.substring(0, soapEndpoint.indexOf("Soap/"))
            + "async/" + apiVersion;
        config.setRestEndpoint(restEndpoint);
        // This should only be false when doing debugging.
        config.setCompression(true);
        // Set this to true to see HTTP requests and responses on stdout
        config.setTraceMessage(false);
        BulkConnection connection = new BulkConnection(config);
        return connection;
    }



    /**
     * Create and upload batches using a CSV file.
     * The file into the appropriate size batch files.
     * 
     * @param connection
     *            Connection to use for creating batches
     * @param jobInfo
     *            Job associated with new batches
     * @param csvFileName
     *            The source file for batch data
     */
    private List<BatchInfo> createBatchesFromCSVFile(BulkConnection connection,
          JobInfo jobInfo, String csvFileName)
            throws IOException, AsyncApiException {
        List<BatchInfo> batchInfos = new ArrayList<BatchInfo>();
        BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(csvFileName))
        );
        // read the CSV header row
        byte[] headerBytes = (rdr.readLine() + "\n").getBytes("UTF-8");
        int headerBytesLength = headerBytes.length;
        File tmpFile = File.createTempFile("bulkAPIInsert", ".csv");

        // Split the CSV file into multiple batches
        try {
            FileOutputStream tmpOut = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);
            int maxBytesPerBatch = 10000000; // 10 million bytes per batch
            int maxRowsPerBatch = 10000; // 10 thousand rows per batch
            int currentBytes = 0;
            int currentLines = 0;
            String nextLine;
            while ((nextLine = rdr.readLine()) != null) {
                byte[] bytes = (nextLine + "\n").getBytes("UTF-8");
                // Create a new batch when our batch size limit is reached
                if (currentBytes + bytes.length > maxBytesPerBatch
                  || currentLines > maxRowsPerBatch) {
                    createBatch(tmpOut, tmpFile, batchInfos, connection, jobInfo);
                    currentBytes = 0;
                    currentLines = 0;
                }
                if (currentBytes == 0) {
                    tmpOut = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);
                    tmpOut.write(headerBytes);
                    currentBytes = headerBytesLength;
                    currentLines = 1;
                }
                tmpOut.write(bytes);
                currentBytes += bytes.length;
                currentLines++;
            }
            // Finished processing all rows
            // Create a final batch for any remaining data
            if (currentLines > 1) {
                createBatch(tmpOut, tmpFile, batchInfos, connection, jobInfo);
            }
        } finally {
            tmpFile.delete();
        }
        return batchInfos;
    }

    /**
     * Create a batch by uploading the contents of the file.
     * This closes the output stream.
     * 
     * @param tmpOut
     *            The output stream used to write the CSV data for a single batch.
     * @param tmpFile
     *            The file associated with the above stream.
     * @param batchInfos
     *            The batch info for the newly created batch is added to this list.
     * @param connection
     *            The BulkConnection used to create the new batch.
     * @param jobInfo
     *            The JobInfo associated with the new batch.
     */
    private void createBatch(FileOutputStream tmpOut, File tmpFile,
      List<BatchInfo> batchInfos, BulkConnection connection, JobInfo jobInfo)
              throws IOException, AsyncApiException {
        tmpOut.flush();
        tmpOut.close();
        FileInputStream tmpInputStream = new FileInputStream(tmpFile);
        try {
            BatchInfo batchInfo =
              connection.createBatchFromStream(jobInfo, tmpInputStream);
            System.out.println(batchInfo);
            batchInfos.add(batchInfo);

        } finally {
            tmpInputStream.close();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Hi,

i tried implementing an example of bulk api provided at :
 http://code.google.com/p/sfdc-bulkapi-demo/source/browse/trunk/demo/src/com/jeffdouglas/BulkLoader.java

At run time, i am getting following error :
com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: Failed to send request to https://www.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/29.0

How can i solve it, Please help.